# speeding up a python code with 2 for loops

Tags: python, performance, file

I have the following python code snippet that I would like to speed up:

```
in_file1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')

for line1 in in_file:
    col1,col2,col3,col4=line1.rstrip.split("\t")
    with open('flie2.txt', 'r') as in_file2:
        for line2 in in_file2:
            col1,col2,col3,col4=line2.rstrip.split("\t")
            if col1 in line1 == col1 in line2:
                print the line from file2
```

File sizes are in GB. Can anyone suggest a way (or ways) to replace the for loops to speed up the code?

Thanks

Comment: why are you opening the file in the loop?

Comment: sorry guys. code now edited to address your questions. just trying compare the contents of two huge files that need speeding up

Comment: so you want to compare the first  element from every line in file1 to the same in file2?

Comment: @user27976 What is the size of these files?` Also the variables are still messed up, you're using the same variable names twice.

Comment: You're redefining `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` in the nested for loop, so line 4 in your example is completely redundant.

Comment: yes to compare first element from every line in file1 to the same in file2

Comment: File sizes are in GB

Answer (score 2):

You could make a set of the first elements from file1 and then test for membership

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as in_file1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as in_file2:
    cols_set = {line.split("\t", 1)[0] for line in in_file1}
    for line in in_file2:
        if line.split("\t",1)[0] in cols_set:
            print(line)
```

Comment: This will definitely reduce the time complexity. But considering files are huge(GB), OP might run out of memory.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, that is a possibility, it is also possible that it will work and be a lot more efficient but without knowing exactly how big "huge" is or how much memory the OP has to work with it is rather futile discussing.

Comment: you compare if the first element of lines of file2 is "present" on first element of lines of file1, but you dont check if it s the same line

Comment: @LudovicViaud, what do you think the nested loop is doing in the OP's code? `if col1 in line1 == col1 in line2:` If the OP was comparing line for line that would be a lot simpler

Comment: ok I misunderstand cause op said "yes to compare first element from every line in file1 to the same in file2", I thought he spoke about the same line

Comment: OP code would output a matching `line2` as many times as there are matching lines in `file1` (would if it worked).

Comment: @gboffi, my code will do exactly what the OP's should be  doing except once memory is not an issue, it will be doing it a hell of a lot faster

Comment: Your code is fast, and prints either 0 or 1 time a line from file2.

Answer (score 1):

If both memory and performance are an issue then you could use a generator to break the files into manageable sized chunks which are read into memory, and compare each chunk in file 1 to each chunk in file 2. Also note that we can pay attention only to the first column in file 1, so do not have to store the rest of the lines in memory.

```
def get_chunks(file_name, lines, operation=lambda x:x):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        chunk = []
        for line in file:
            chunk.append(operation(line))
            if len(chunk) == lines:
                yield chunk
                chunk = []

def get_first_column(line):
    return line.split('\t')[0]

for chunk1 in get_chunks('file1.txt', 10000, operation=get_first_column):
    for chunk2 in get_chunks('file2.txt', 1000):
        for line in chunk2:
            if get_first_column(line) in chunk1:
                print line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_func(file_name_1, file_name_2):
    for line_1 in open(file_name_1):
        for line_2 in open(file_name_2):
            if line_1.split('\t')[0] == line_2.split('\t')[0]:
                yield line_2
```

usage :

```
for line in my_func('file1.txt', 'file2.txt'):
    print(line)
```